# Calculate the number of days a person has been alive on his Nth birthday? (Leap year challenge)

Tags: algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I calculate the age of a person in year, month, days?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453208/how-can-i-calculate-the-age-of-a-person-in-year-month-days)

How to calculate the number of days that person has been alive on his Nth birthday? given his birth month, day, year, and his age? How to solve the leap year challenge?

Comment: see this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453208/how-can-i-calculate-the-age-of-a-person-in-year-month-days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453208/how-can-i-calculate-the-age-of-a-person-in-year-month-days) Bye.

Comment: See also metashockwave's other related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381832/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a (sort of a) one-liner in Perl:

```
$ perl -MPOSIX -e '($d, $m, $y, $a) = @ARGV; print ((mktime(0,0,0,$d,$m+1,$y+$a-1900) - mktime(0,0,0,$d,$m+1,$y-1900)) / 86400)' 23 4 1975 29
10593
```

Of course, this passes off the key leap year calculations to the `POSIX::mktime` function.